# GRUB slow/irresponsive when in UEFI bios mode

Tags: grub2, nvidia, uefi

I have a GTX 1060 GPU, a ultrawide (21:9) 2560x1080 monitor and a MSI B-450 A PRO motherboard (bios version `V10.C` - 2019/11/12).

And i want to have my grub fullscreen (in my case 2560x1080p)

Recently i've change the bootmode of my bios from CSM to UEFI.
after this my grub started to use the monitor resolution (2560x1080), before it only supported no more than 1920x1080.

After this change the grub is EXTREMELY slow,to the level where i can see the screen beeing renderized, and i have to take care to not type too fast (not even medium speed) in the Grub shell, or it will miss the key presses.

my /etc/default/grub have this content:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="4"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="2560x1080x32"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
#GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND="efi_gop"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"

GRUB_THEME="/usr/share/grub/themes/Stylish/theme.txt"
```

two gifs showing how slow it renders:

[entering main grub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui4sm.gif)

[entering grub shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9E7v.gif)

here's the [full video link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EZRmxA23_Yg1I0F7N-y_o5-7-nidMraF) to google drive, in this video it shows also me typing (you can hear the key presses) and how slow it takes the input.

does anyone know what is happening, and how to fix it?

note: i've already tried without the custom theme, but it behaves the same way (slow)

Edit: added gif and video file

Comment: @Nmath i've checked my bootloader and it is GRUB 2.04.

Comment: Sorry but problem not solved. I want to have a fullscreen Grub, not 1920x1080 where the lateral edges are just empty black (yes, for aesthetic).
My system boots in any mode, but in UEFI the GRUB rendering is slow, the remaining boot steps are actually quicker in UEFI.
How the way an operating system was installed can affect GRUB (a bootloader) graphical perfomance? I don't undestand a lot of bootloaders.

Comment: Grub now tries to use default video from system. But you have set to one mode with the gfxmode setting. But to get correct video with nVidia, you must install nVidia proprietary driver. Either during install or as first boot. If you change or install a second video driver, you get conflicts as new one does not un-install older one. If using nomodeset boot parameter  to boot, or grub's recovery boot then you do get low resolution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it